# android : Navigation Drawer with the ImaveView to the right of the listView

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I need to put the image to the right of the Navigation Drawer in android

Some like this ( image on which arrow points) :

[image]

So the background transparancy should stay the same , but with the ImageView besides the ListView.

I found on different tutorial, but didn't find such implementation.

My NavigationDrawer :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: List view item layout defines how your item looks in navigation drawer. Where is code for listview item layout

Comment: No, I've implemented the icon above the text in the listView. I used custom BaseAdapter with corresponding layout. The question is how implement the image at the navigation drawer background - the arrow on the image is pointing on what I need to implement.

Comment: try setting that as background for framelayout or listview. #crosscheck hope it may work